# increase number of threads decrease time

Tags: multithreading, openmp

I'm newbie in openmp. Beginning with a tutorial from the official page of openmp
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLLX-Q6B8xqZ8n8bwjGdzBJ25X2utwnoEG

In that page there is a hello world program to calculate pi by an approximation of integral.
I simply wrote the code below following the instructions but the time-speed of it increase as I increase the number of threads changing the NUM_THREADS. In the video, the speed goes down.

I'm executing the program in a remote server with 64 cpus having 8 cores each.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
static long num_steps = 100000;
double step;

#define NUM_THREADS 2 

int main()
{
    int i, nthreads; double pi, sum[NUM_THREADS];
    double start_t;

    step = 1.0 / (double) num_steps;

    omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);

    start_t = omp_get_wtime();
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        int i, id, nthrds;
        double x;

        id = omp_get_thread_num();
        nthrds = omp_get_num_threads();
        if (id == 0) nthreads = nthrds;
        for (i = id, sum[id] = 0.0; i < num_steps; i = i + nthrds) {
            x = (i + 0.5) * step;
            sum[id] += 4.0 / (1.0 + x*x);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0, pi = 0.0; i < nthreads; i++) {
        pi += sum[i] * step;
    }
    printf("%f\n", omp_get_wtime() - start_t);
}
```

Comment: Did you mean remote server with 8 cores and 8 threads per core?

Comment: Yes, 8 cores 8 threads per core.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bad approach to implementing reduction using shared arrays. The successive elements of `sum` are too close to each other and therefore reside in the same cache line. On cache-coherent architectures like x86/x64, this leads to a problem known as *false sharing*. The following simple modification will get rid of it:

```c
double sum[8*NUM_THREADS];

#pragma omp parallel
{
    ...
    for (i = id, sum[id] = 0.0; i < num_steps; i = i + nthrds) {
        ...
        sum[8*id] += 4.0 / (1.0 + x*x);
    }
}
for (i = 0, pi = 0.0; i < nthreads; i++) {
    pi += sum[8*i] * step;
}
```

Only the relevant changes are shown. The idea is simple: instead of having threads access successive elements of `sum`, make them access every 8-th element. Thus it is guaranteed that threads do not share the same cache line as on most modern CPUs a cache line is 64 bytes long and that corresponds to `64 / sizeof(double)` = 8 array elements.

Edit: my mistake, should have watched the video in the first place. False sharing is explained just after the results from running the code are shown. If you don't get any speedup in your case, that's probably because newer CPU generations handle false sharing better.

Comment: If you are doing a reduction you should let OpenMP do it for you by using the "reduction" clause on the "omp parallel". That way you dont' need to worry about its implementation, just leave it to the implementation on each machine to do the right thing, and you avoid the need for the global array completely.

Comment: The `reduction` clause comes later ;)

Comment: Our teaching style is different :-). I'd explain reduction before getting into cache issues, because reduction is a high-level (semantic) concept, whereas the cache-issues are low-level, implementation ones that take us down into the hardware. For the people whose answer to "Explain machine code?" is "Well, there's this thing called the Java Virtual Machine", you're biting off an awful lot by leaping to cache-contention when their problem can be solved by "Let the compiler do the reduction for you".

Comment: Who am I to argue with the teaching style of Tim Mattson? :) Turned out the code is deliberately written that way and the introduction of false sharing comes immediately after.